# How to change kendo chart legend item color on unselect?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

dynamically Change The Kendo chart legend unselect on apply custom color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [
      { data: [6, 2, 3], name: "Task 1" },
      { data: [1, 5, 2], name: "Task 2" }
    ],
    legendItemClick: function(e){
        e.sender.options.legend.inactiveItems.markers.color = "red";
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

   
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="chart"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
series: [
  { data: [6, 2, 3], name: "Task 1" },
  { data: [1, 5, 2], name: "Task 2" }
],
legendItemClick: function(e){
    e.sender.options.legend.inactiveItems.markers.color = "red";
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
 e.sender.options.legend.inactiveItems.markers.color = "<Use Your Custom Color>";
```

This Line Of Code Place At LegendItemClick Templet Or Function.I think.... This is Use full To Succeed  Your need.